# ¿Con qué argumentos darían por correcta la forma "Van a ser X meses/años desde que..." (en lugar de "va a hacer X meses/años desde que...")?

Tags: gramática

A partir de un mensaje de whatsapp que escribí, me surgió una duda (no existencial, pero casi). Quería recriminarle a alguien que no había cumplido un compromiso o que se había excedido en un plazo, y escribí:

- Ya **va a hacer** tres meses desde que firmamos el convenio (y nada ha ocurrido).

En la lengua hablada, me sonaba familiar el plural "van a ser" (descarté "van a hacer" porque "hacer" es impersonal en esas construcciones y por lo tanto siempre se conjuga en tercera persona del singular), y se me ocurrió buscar en Google Books (sólo busqué "tres meses", pero otras combinaciones de meses y años serían posibles). Curiosamente, encontré varios ejemplos:

> "**Van a ser** tres meses desde que la vi esa vez." ([Fuente](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=IbpUk0i7pDYC&pg=PT57&dq=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyvLnyou_YAhVHFpAKHZkGCGAQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&f=false))
>
> "**Van a ser** tres meses que nos hemos quedado sin ella." ([Fuente](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=lzvdCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyvLnyou_YAhVHFpAKHZkGCGAQ6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&f=false))
>
> "El sábado **van a ser** tres meses desde que Rafael entró en el hospital con múltiples fracturas." ([Fuente](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=_dzEBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&dq=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnwczYpe_YAhVEGpAKHeCMBzg4ChDoAQgvMAI#v=onepage&q=%22van%20a%20ser%20tres%20meses%22&f=false))

Encontré —debo decir— más ejemplos (aparentemente más confiables) de la forma que considero correcta, "va a hacer tres meses".

Quienes crean que la forma (para mí objetable) "van a ser X meses/años" es correcta, favor argumentar. Cualquier fuente que avale o justifique el uso de "van a ser X meses/años" será apreciada.

Comment: @walen Modifiqué la pregunta para que, si lo deseas, coloques tu comentario como respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: A mi personalmente "van a ser" para indicar que ha pasado x tiempo me suena bastante mal pero no sé si es correcto. ¿Es posible que en zonas seseantes o ceceantes "va a ser" y "va a hacer"  al sonar prácticamente igual se confundan a veces? A lo mejor es una bobada pero es una idea

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo que es porobable que se deba a una distorsión por seseo

`a hacer → a a ser → a ser.`

Sin embargo, me parece muy bella la versatilidad de nuestro idioma, pues igualmente se pueden encontrar argumentos que conviertan la segunda en válida. Es tan simple como suponer una elipsis de la palabra "cumplidos".

> Van a ser cumplidos tres meses...

También valdrían otros sinónimos. Es solo un posible argumento que se me ha ocurrido, algo artificial, pero podría servir para "salvar" esa expresión.

Comment: Apoyo el argumento de la elipsis (aun a riesgo de parecer racionalizando o justificando ese uso) porque le agrega una potencia dúctil y expresiva a la frase (*ya **va hacer** tres meses desde que firmamos el convenio*, donde  *hacer* es igual a *haber  transcurrido*, o *ir a convertirse el lapso en*, etc)

Answer (score 1):

No sé si puedo justificar "van a ser" lo suficiente para tí, porque tu español es impecable.  Y la verdad creo que "va a hacer" es mejor.  Sin embargo "van a ser" no me parece horrible y te doy mi justificación.  No tengo fuente sino lógica nomás, perdón.

Considera

> Van a ser tres gatos en una casa cuando llegue la tía de visita de verano con su gata.

En este sentido, "Van a ser X meses desde que..." parece razonable.  Pero para expresiones de tiempo, "hacer" es la herramienta más adecuada, como por ejemplo

> Hace X meses que llegó la tía de visita con su gata.

Sospecho que la influencia del inglés ha tenido algo que ver con los enlaces que encontraste con "van a ser".